# Conditional grouping in scala maps without loop

Tags: scala, maps

Is it possible to group only specific elements in a scala map which matches a given condition?

**From:**

```
 val map = Map(((1,true,"case0")->List(1,2,3)), ((2,true,"case0")->List(3,4,5)), 
 ((1,true,"case1")->List(2,4,6)), ((2,false,"case1")->List(3)))
```

**To:**

```
Map(((1,true,"nocase")->List(2)), ((2,true,"case0")->List(3,4,5)), 
((2,false,"case1")->List(3)))
```

**Condition:**

key._1 should match and key._2 should be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is way

```
map.groupBy(
   e => (e._1._1, e._1._2)  //group input by key._1 and key._2 
).collect{
   case e if (e._2.keys.size > 1)=>       // if key have more cases(key._3) use "nocase" 
      (e._1._1, e._1._2, "nocase") ->     //Tuple3(Int, Boolean, String)
      e._2.values.reduce(_.intersect(_))  //List of common elements
   case e =>                              //we have only one key._3 so use as it is
      (e._1._1, e._1._2, e._2.map(e=> e._1._3).mkString("")) -> 
      e._2.values.reduce(_.intersect(_))
}
```

### Output

```
Map((2,false,case1) -> List(3), (2,true,case0) -> List(3, 4, 5), (1,true,nocase) -> List(2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain the significance of below line?                                                                                                                    case e => (e._1._1, e._1._2, e._2.map(e=> e._1._3).mkString("")) -> e._2.values.reduce(_.intersect(_))

Comment: we are trying to `collect` the grouped elements based on the `map` key size. When there is only one key present we make take the string (if not we get a `List[String]`) by joining this one key with no delimiter.

Comment: Curious to know if we can achieve the same without using ._1._1. Because usage of _ makes this less readable.

Comment: @Srivignesh It is not possible to use `_` as we have more than a operation for a collect `case` however to learn by your self, you can remove those internal calls with in `case` of `collect` and keep learning them.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the `groupBy` on a conditional basis

```
map.groupBy{case (key, value) => if (key._1 == 1) (key._1, key._2) else key }
.map{case (key, elements) => (key, elements.values.reduce(_ intersect _ ))}
```

In this piece of code, you will use the whole key (3 elements) to group if the first element of the key is not 1, otherwise it will group by only the first and second elements of the key

**Output**:

```
 Map((2,true,case0) -> List(3, 4, 5), (2,false,case1) -> List(3), (1,true) -> List(2))
```

Comment: Did you mean groupByKey? In the code snippet I still see groupBy being used.

Comment: I mean groupBy. Sorry